# How to check if channel is full without sending anything

Tags: go, concurrency

I know I can check if a channel is full by trying to send it something like this:

```
select {
    case ch <- "data":
        // sent
    default:
        // channel full
}
```

However, is there a way to check if a channel is full without sending anything?

Comment: i wonder why you need that. I dont see why you would not put your alternative logic within the default case.

Answer (score 2):

`cap(ch)` returns the buffer capacity for channel `ch`
`len(ch)` returns the number of unprocessed messages currently in channel `ch`

So to check if a channel is full, you can do:

```
cap(ch) == len(ch)
```

Comment: This is mostly useless, since the main purpose of channels is for concurrent synchronization, and if there is the possibility of any concurrent access, the resulting value is always stale.

Comment: I've seen something like this used for "high watermark" checking... `len(ch) == cap(ch)*8/10`. So it can be useful sometimes. Also strictly speaking the dupe is wrong.